# Can an injection of unipotent stem cells cause teratoma?

Tags: stem-cells, gene-therapy

I understand that injecting pluripotent stem cells causes formation of teratomas.

Does injecting unipotent stem cells also cause teratoma?

If it does not form teratoma, is the injection of unipotent stem cells a safer way to heal/regenerate the tissue that was damaged?

Comment: As I understand it they are less harmful because unipotent stem cells differentiate into only one specific cell type and form a single lineage, whereas pluripotent stem cells can develop into all three germ layers, which can result into teratoma, but an injection of unipotent hESC can also form malignant tumors (which teratoma can as well -> A "benign" grade 0 (mature) teratoma nonetheless has a risk of malignancy. Recurrence with malignant endodermal sinus tumor has been reported in cases of formerly benign mature teratoma, even in fetiform teratoma). Just my understanding - hence the comment

Comment: _"Can an injection of unipotent stem cells cause teratoma?"_ No, because they form a single lineage and therefore can't lead to teratoma or so called dermoid cyst/twin cyst. _"..is the injection of unipotent stem cells a safer way to heal/regenerate the tissue that was damaged?"_ remains to be answered by someone with more knowledge and sources of scientific research regarding this topic..

Comment: Sir/Mdm, what does hESC stand for?

Comment: Human Embryonic Stem Cells - often abreviated as HESC or hESC